# Sql update query in python code

Tags: python, oracle, python-2.7, python-3.x, cx-oracle

I have written the below code but it is not working
it is telling ORA-01008: not all variables bound.
cur.execute("update  python set id = :10 where id = :1")

Comment: from the type of error I am guessing you are using Oracle, you should however add more info

Comment: The stuff starting with `:` are *placeholders* for values that are substituted in place. Try `cur.execute("update python set id = 10 where id = 1")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Oracle interpreter see colons, it expects to use bound variables, which will be provided separately.

In your case you should remove colons:

`update python set id = 10 where id = 1`